# Null Pointer Exception Java GUI Application SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, exception, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run a simple sql query but am getting a Null pointer exception.
I tried to change everything possible but could not figure out the reason for this exception.

My part of code :

```
String sql = "Insert into CG (Date,Day,Pre,Sub) values (?,?,?,?)";
        try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, "date");//4 value taken as input
        pst.setString(2, "day");
        pst.setString(3, "1");
        pst.setString(4, "0");
        pst.execute();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

**Edit** : I am getting NPE at line pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)

```
       My connection is :
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:\\NetBeansProject\\At\\At.sqlite");
```

Comment: @Masud I edited showing where I got NPE.

Comment: Your conn is null. Did you intialize conn like `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection()`?

Comment: If that is where you are getting the NPE - then conn is NULL. Where do you initialize conn, why could it be NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);`